# Reading an InputStream in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java thus the question,

I'm using the following class to read a file into a string.

```
public class Reader {

    public static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I modify the method signature of read to read a InputStream as opposed to a string.

Comment: I'm new to Java, down voter your argument please ?

Comment: YOu mean just send it an `InputStream` and then just do... `BufferedInputStream st = new BufferedInputStream(*PARAMETER*);` ??

Comment: Are you looking for `public static String readInputStream(InputStream stream)` or `public static InputStream readFile(String filename)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `String` argument and create an argument of type `InputStream`. Pass this argument to the constructor of an `InputStreamReader` and this `InputStreamReader` can be passed to the constructor of your `BufferedReader`.

```
public static String readFile(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Maybee you want to try a try-with-resource statement. Then you can remove the final block. It looks like this.

```
public static String readFile(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea this was so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not for educational purposes, don't do this manually. E.g. you could use [IOUtils.toString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache Commons.